# How do I Import and run 2 scripts in SS 2.x?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a suitescript that imports 2 scripts. When the user presses a button it is supposed to run the first script and then the 2nd script. My issue is that only the function for the 1st script is running. The 2nd script is not and I see no errors in console. What am I missing?

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 */

define(['N/ui/dialog', './stdRates.js', './specialRates.js'], (dialog, stdRates, specialRates) => {

    function pageInit(context) {}

    function selectRateType(context) {
        const options = {
            title: 'Select Rate Types',
            message: 'Select the type of rates you want to import.',
            buttons: [{
                    label: 'To Client',
                    value: 1
                },

                {
                    label: 'Return',
                    value: 2
                }

            ]
        };

        function success(result) {

            stdRates.stdRates();
            specialRates.specialRates();
}

        function failure(reason) {
            console.log(`Failure: ${reason}`)
        }

        dialog.create(options).then(success).catch(failure);
    }

    return {
        selectRateType,
        pageInit
    };
});
```

Comment: you'd probably need to post the other two scripts

Comment: We would need to see the other scripts to help here...

 Have you placed logs all over the second script to see if it runs at all and if it dose where it fails?

Comment: Try calling only one at a time. I would assume they are both running, but one of them is just not doing what you think it should. The script may not be encountering an error at all, and just may not be written correctly. Try adding a console.log() in each script to make sure both scripts are running.